# How to have an amplified signal as an input to amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have a turntable that already does the amplification inside the product. However, I want to connect the turntable to the amplifier I have next to it, so I can control everything from there.

Is it a problem to connect the amplified signal to the amplifier?

If yes. What can I do to unamplify the signal in order to connect it to the amplifier?

Comment: Is your turntable outputting a line level, through RCA connectors, a headphone output through a 3.5mm jack, or a loudspeaker signal through some form of binding post/clips/wires? If the former two, just connecting it to a line level input (AUX in, CD in etc) at your amp will be simple. If speakers, you need to make sure you've got the right line/ground wires, and it's not a bridged output.

Comment: It has a 6,3 mm (1/4") jack output and 2-pins DIN outputs that can go directly to the speakers. Can the headphone output (6.3mm) be used like you said about the 3.5mm jack?

Comment: If it has a 6.35mm jack output, that is most probably line level audio, or possibly headphone level (about the same) so it can connect into an aux/tuner/tape input (NOT PHONO OR TURNTABLE  INPUT!) on another amp. Phono/Turntable input is usually far too sensitive and has RIAA frequency response shaping, which your turntable already does internally.

Comment: Since the Phono input is the only available slot left, is there a way to turn the output signal of the turntable into a signal that can enter the phono input?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this "turntable" includes a power amplifier (meant to drive speakers directly), it is most likely putting out *line level* audio.  This is what comes out of a standard preamp, and is what power amps expect as input.

The most likely solution is then to connect the turntable output to a "line in" input of the amplifier.

A better answer requires a better question, including some real specs on what exactly this turntable put out, and what the various input option of the amplifier are.